# The number of components of the preimage of a continuum for a polynomial

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-dynamics, continuum-theory

Given a polynomial f with degree d, we can define a dynamical system $(\mathbb{C}, f)$. If we have a proper continuum $N \subset \mathbb{C}$, it is known that the set $f^{-1}(N)$ has at most $d$ components, with each component being mapped onto $N$ by $f$. This fact can be found in [pp95, Lemma 5.7.2, Beardon, Alan F.'s “Iteration of Rational Functions” in the book “Complex Analytic Dynamical Systems” (Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 132, Springer-Verlag, New York, 1991)].

The question now arises: if we further assume that the continuum $N$ is full (meaning both $N$ and its complement are connected) and does not contain the image of critical points (referred to as critical values and the cricital points mean the points at which the derivative of $f$ is zero), can we then conclude that there are exactly $d$ components of $f^{-1}(N)$, and that $f$ is injective when restricted to each component?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. First construct a Jordan domain $D$ which contains
your continuum and does not contain any critical values. (To do this map the simply connected domain $\overline{\mathbf{C}}\setminus N$ conformally onto the unit disk by a function $\phi$, then $\phi^{-1}(\{ z:|z|=r\})$ will be a Jordan curve if $r$ is close enough to $1$, and the
interior region $D$ of this curve will contain $N$ and contain no critical values). Then the restriction
$$f: f^{-1}(D)\to D$$
is an (unramified) covering map of degree $d$, therefore it
consists on $d$ simply connected components. Each component
contains exactly one component of $f^{-1}(N)$.

Comment: TeX note: `\setminus` spaces better than `\backslash` for complements, e.g., $\mathbb C \backslash f^{-1}(D)$ `\mathbb C \backslash f^{-1}(D)` vs. $\mathbb C \setminus f^{-1}(D)$ `\mathbb C \setminus f^{-1}(D)`.  I edited accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice: Thanks, I will try to remember this.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer, here the restriction should be $f: f^{-1}(D)\rightarrow D$, right? So the fact is that for any (unramified) covering map $f: X \subset\mathbb{C}\rightarrow X$ of degree $d$,  the set $f^{-1}(N)$ has eaxctly $d$ components  for any full continuum $N \subset X$.

Comment: @Yee Neil: Thanks. You are right. I corrected the formula.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have remembered an important proposition

Comment: @YeeNeil Since you seem interested in dynamics, note that the argument that Alexandre outlined can be used to show that the Julia set of a polynomial is a Cantor set provided all critical points iterate to infinity.